# Vue Apollo Query error module build failed

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, apollo, vue-apollo

so basically i want to do a query using Apollo Query in Vue 2 CLI. but it is not working, i dont know what is the problem. maybe someone can help me? i have stuck for 3 hours withour any progress

here is the code

```
<ApolloQuery
          :query="
            (gql) => gql`
              query MyQuery {
                fasilitas {
                  judul
                  judul_second
                  deskripsi
                  foto
                }
              }
            `
          "
        >
          <template v-slot="{ result: { loading, error, data } }">
            <div v-if="loading" class="loading apollo">Loading...</div>

            <div v-else-if="error" class="error apollo">An error occurred</div>

            <div v-else-if="data" class="result apollo">{{ data.fasilitas }}</div>

            <div v-else class="no-result apollo">No result :(</div>
          </template>
        </ApolloQuery>
```

and here is the error

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                           01:44:40

 error  in ./src/views/IndexView.vue?vue&type=template&id=78027b66&

Syntax Error: Error
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)


ERROR in ./src/views/IndexView.vue?vue&type=template&id=78027b66& (./node_modules/@vue/vue-loader-v15/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js??vue-loader-options!./node_modules/@vue/vue-loader-v15/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./src/views/IndexView.vue?vue&type=template&id=78027b66&)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@vue/vue-loader-v15/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js):
Error
    at Node.initialise (D:\PNJ\Kampus Merdeka\Alterra Academy\vue_mini-project_roland-brilianto\node_modules\vue-template-es2015-compiler\buble.js:16016:10)
    at D:\PNJ\Kampus Merdeka\Alterra Academy\vue_mini-project_roland-brilianto\node_modules\vue-template-es2015-compiler\buble.js:7993:51
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
webpack compiled with 1 error
```

Answer (score 0):

i struggled with the same issue. you have to add the tag setup to your vue.config.js.

https://apollo.vuejs.org/guide/components/query.html#tag-setup

Comment: Please add a code sample in case the source location changes.